# Is there a way to strip the seconds off of this string?

Tags: javascript, html, string

I am trying to make this string show as MM/DD/YYYY, HH:MM AM/PM without the seconds and I have tried to use slice() but that is not working as I would like it to.

```
<p style="font-family:verdana"><span id="datetime"></span></p>
<script>
    var dt = new Date(); 
    document.getElementById("datetime").innerHTML = dt.toLocaleString(); 
</script>
```

Comment: What have you tried with `slice`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass an options object as the second parameter to [`Date#toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString).

```js
var dt = new Date();
document.getElementById("datetime").innerHTML = dt.toLocaleString('en-US', {
  year: 'numeric',
  month: '2-digit',
  day: '2-digit',
  hour: '2-digit',
  minute: '2-digit'
});
```

```html
<p style="font-family:verdana"><span id="datetime"></span></p>
```

Comment: @DaConnz No problem.

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe slice lets you take things out in the middle. Splice can do that but it works with arrays. I think the easiest way to get it to work is to slice the dt twice, like this:

`dt.toLocaleString().slice(0,15)+dt.toLocaleString().slice(18)`

It should output like:

`"8/21/2021, 5:14 PM"`